# Mapping XML input stream to JCR

Tags: java, xml, metadata, aem, jcr

I am working on Adobe CQ. I am extracting metadata for Raw files, and getting metadata as `IIOMetadata` object.

I am mapping XML input stream to JCR, by `session.importXml`
but since my XML is like

```
<parentTag name ="" value =""><child tag.....</parentTage>
```

(it mean there is nothing like `parent : properties`, no use of colon mark)

So after mapping, I am getting all the properties name as node, and there value as node property, because of this there is hell no. of nodes.

Can you tell me is there any way to correctly map?

**note:**
I am extracting Metadata from CRW files, and I am getting `IIOMetadata` as an object. 
then I am converting this `IIOMetadata` object to XML input stream. and then mapping by `session.import`

```
ImageReader reader = ImageIO.getImageReaders(tempFile).next();
final IIOMetadata metadata = reader.getImageMetadata(0);

String[] mdatanames = metadata.getMetadataFormatNames();

for(int i=0;i &lt mdatanames.length; i++)
{

    Node metadatadom = metadata.getAsTree(mdatanames[i]);

    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(metadatadom);

    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    StreamResult result1 = new StreamResult(writer);

    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(os);

    Transformer transformer =                   

    TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.transform(source, result);
    transformer.transform(source, result1);

    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new  

    ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());
    String nodePath1 = asset.getPath() + "/jcr:content/metadata" ;
    session.importXML(nodePath1, bais,       
    ImportUUIDBehavior.IMPORT_UUID_CREATE_NEW);

    String  metadata_in_xml = writer.toString();
}
```

I have used `ImportUUIDBehavior.IMPORT_UUID_COLLISION_REPLACE_EXISTING`  too.

Please help.. 
I want to map metadata like default mapping happens like for DNG file and other supported files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should manually iterate over all properties and children nodes of the `IIOMetadata` object and create related JCR nodes and properties under the asset. Creating and transforming XML representation is an overkill (assuming that it's possible at all).

I don't have much experience with `IIOMetadata` files, but you may start with something like that:

```
import com.day.cq.dam.api.Asset;
import javax.imageio.metadata.IIOMetadata;
import javax.jcr.Node;
import javax.jcr.RepositoryException;
import org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.JcrUtils;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource;
import org.w3c.dom.DOMException;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

...

public void writeMetadataToNode(IIOMetadata metadata, Asset asset) throws RepositoryException {
    Resource resource = asset.adaptTo(Resource.class);
    Node metadataNode = resource.getChild("jcr:content/metadata").adaptTo(Node.class);
    for (String formatName : metadata.getMetadataFormatNames()) {
        Node formatNode = JcrUtils.getOrAddNode(metadataNode, formatName);
        org.w3c.dom.Node domRoot = metadata.getAsTree(formatName);
        copyDomToJcr(formatNode, domRoot);
    }
    metadataNode.getSession().save();
}

private void copyDomToJcr(Node jcrNode, org.w3c.dom.Node domNode) throws DOMException, RepositoryException {
    NamedNodeMap attributes = domNode.getAttributes();
    for (int i = 0; i < attributes.getLength(); i++) {
        org.w3c.dom.Node attribute = attributes.item(i);
        jcrNode.setProperty(attribute.getNodeName(), attribute.getNodeValue());
    }
    NodeList children = domNode.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
        org.w3c.dom.Node child = children.item(i);
        Node newJcrNode = JcrUtils.getOrAddNode(jcrNode, child.getNodeName());
        copyDomToJcr(newJcrNode, child);
    }
}
```

The first method creates JCR node for each metadata format. The second copies all DOM attributes to the new node and then, recursively, creates JCR node for each DOM node child.

I don't know if this is a desired format. You may skip the first level (nodes with format names) and write attributes directly to the `metadata` node. In order to do that remove `formatNode` from the first method and replace it with `metadataNode`. Feel free to experiment and adjust the results to your requirements.